# Why does specifying a wildcard for a test class name cause Maven to open empty browsers with WebDriver?

Tags: maven, selenium, junit, webdriver

To make a long story short, I am attempting to use Maven to run Selenium WebDriver integration tests. (These are JUnit tests.)  To do this, I can issue a command like:

```
mvn -Dit.test=MyTestClass#MyTestMethod verify
```

Specifically, I would like to do this:

```
mvn -Dit.test=*#*CaseID*  verify
```

In the above command, CaseID is actually a number corresponding to the test case in my test case management system. This actually works, in that it runs the test method whose method name matches the case ID.

However, when I use a * wildcard for the test class name, I actually get several Chrome windows being started as ChromeDriver instances, and then my actual test method will run afterwards.

Why is this happening, and how can I debug it to find out which of my test classes is causing the errant browser windows? I already thought that perhaps some older test classes (with the WebDriver instance initialized as one of the class fields, not initialized in a Junit @Method or constructor) but that doesn't appear to be the cause of the problem. I edited one of those classes to move initialization to somewhere that only runs if the actual test will be run, and I still got random Chrome windows.

Here is an example of what I thought could cause the problem:

```
public MyTestClass {
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

@Test
public void testMe(){
driver.get("http://google.com");
}
```

However, changing that does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your expectations are a little off.

mvn just runs *stuff*, depending on what you pass in for the lifecycle. See [this handy intro](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

In your case, you passed in "verify", which from the above link you will notice comes after "test". During "test", mvn hands control over to JUnit. JUnit needs to instantiate each of your classes, and so it fires your line `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`. Which I assume is in every one of your classes? Just for kicks: compare the number of open browsers, and the number of your classes.

Further, for each class that gets fired up, JUnit searches for the test you specified in `it.test=` and runs that. Note that any `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` methods are also run, however `@Before` and `@After` methods are run only if the test is run.

There is no problem. What you describe is the expected behaviour!

Comment: I'm actually using Maven in a subset of its intended use. Our integration tests are completely separated from our actual products, so my Maven project is only used to manage and run tests. I'm running my tests as integration tests using Failsafe, instead of as unit tests using Surefire. In any case, I've already determined that my test classes with initialized fields aren't the problem, but I didn't realize that @BeforeClass will be run even if no test methods were run.  I'll check that out and see if that's what's happening.

Comment: Aha, after some more concerted effort, the problem was exactly what I thought it was, and what SiKing mentioned with regards to class instantiating.